# Replace double backslashes into single backslashes to be processed by ansi-to-html

Tags: javascript, rawstring

I'm trying to process a terminal output. Let's say it's the string "\x1b[01;32mREADME.md". It has a double backslash. If I run `console.log("\\x1b[01;32mREADME.md")`, it only shows a single backslash, but if I pass it to the `toHtml` from ansi-to-html, it doesn't work. And by work, I mean transforming the characters into html.

I tried several solutions involving `replace` or the fact that `\` is `U+5c` in unicode but nothing worked. The options on the library don't help either.

[codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-satoshi-q1z60?file=/src/App.js)

```js
import Convert from "ansi-to-html";

export default function App() {
  const c = new Convert({ escapeXML: true });
  const single = "\x1b[01;32mREADME.md";
  const double = "\\x1b[01;32mREADME.md";

  console.log(double) // prints single backslash
  const res1 = c.toHtml(single);
  const res2 = c.toHtml(double);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      single backslash works:
      <pre>{single}</pre>
      <pre>{res1}</pre>
      <br />
      <br />
      double backslash doesnt work:
      <pre>{double}</pre>
      <pre>{res2}</pre>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Backslash is used for escape sequences, and double backslash outputs a literal single backslash. If you want two literal backslashes, simply put four of them.

Comment: in most of the languages, backslash works as escape sequence, which means the next character will be escaped, for example `"\\"` escaped the second backslash so the string only have 1 backslash, so what you need is basically double the double backslash (`"\\\\"`)

Comment: @Noam I understand it's being escaped. The back-end sends it with a single backslash, and in the process of fetching it, it gets the second slash. But the library only accepts strings with a single slash. I can't make this "\\x1b[01;32mREADME.md" into this "\x1b[01;32mREADME.md" so that the library can generate the correct HTML.

Comment: The double backslash is just a representation, only one backslash is actually stored and would be outputted to the HTML. Also, I don't see any backend fetching in your code so pheraps I don't understand your situaution.

Comment: @Noam I think I saved by mistake while I was playing around with the sandbox. There should be no need to understand how the backend or the communication in general works, the point is if I can convert  "\\x1b[01;32mREADME.md" into "\x1b[01;32mREADME.md" it should work. But because the string is coming from a server it's not like I can manually delete it on the string.

Comment: Yes you can simply do `str.replace('\\\\', '\\')` but there is a chance you are misinterpretting the situation and there is no actual double backslash there.

Comment: I tried that already, it doesn't work. I updated the codesandbox you can see for yourself. The thing that is happening is that the unicode points were being escaped twice. The solution was to not escape them in the back-end.

Comment: So you solved it? (Also don't forget to mention the user you are talking to)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.raw` function:

```
const double = String.raw`\\x1b[01;32mREADME.md`;
```

With this you dont need to use convert:

```js
export default function App() {
  const single = String.raw`\x1b[01;32mREADME.md`;
  const double = String.raw`\\x1b[01;32mREADME.md`;

  const res1 = single;
  const res2 = double;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      single backslash works:
      <pre>{single}</pre>
      <pre>{res1}</pre>
      <br />
      <br />
      double backslash doesnt work:
      <pre>{double}</pre>
      <pre>{res2}</pre>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I tried some variations of that. It doesn't work if you try it in the codesandbox.